# Triangle wall problem

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, geometry

[image: ss]

Hey.
So after following 4 different tutorials (https://raflmao.artstation.com/) and month of inactivity in Blender. I want to make my own project.
I wanna make my room in 3D and I'm having a problem with adding a window on this triangle wall. Actually at height of the loop beetwen triangle and rectangular parts. Any suggestions?
I've tried to add window from Archimesh addon and then use boolean modifier, but I dont know why the interior is still dark like the window isn't rly made of glass.[2[image: ][2]][image: 3]

Comment: Maybe your Interior has no lighting? Try to check if it is lighted up properly.
Also, it might be a simple glitch or some texture issue you have made while UV Mapping. Check how it works if you remove the texture if you did add a texture.

Comment: Editing you .blend file into your question using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ might help.